# convergence of series $\,\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{n^p}\,$

Tags: real-analysis

Discuss the convergence of the series for all $p$.

$$\dfrac{2}{n^{p-\frac{1}{2}}}= \dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{n^p} < \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{n^p} < \dfrac{3\sqrt(n)}{n^p} < \dfrac{3}{n^{p-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

so $\,\sim\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{n^p}\sim\dfrac{K}{n^{p-\frac{1}{2}}}$

converges when $\,p>\dfrac{3}{2},\,$ diverges when $\,p\leq \dfrac{3}{2}\,$

Intuition:
If there exist $\,K,M$ such that, $\,K\cdot b_n<a_n < M\cdot b_n\,$ for all $n$ then $\,a_n\sim b_n\,$

Is my reasoning right?

Comment: Please take a look at this [MathJax basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing math symbols on this website.

Comment: $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{n^p}\le 2n^{-p+1/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your use of $\sim$ (asymptotically equivalent to) is not really necessary here, as we can directly appeal to the comparison theorem. If you need a refresher, the comparison theorem states that if $0\le a_n\le Cb_n$ for some constant $C$, then $\sum_na_n$ will converge if $\sum_nb_n$ converges, and similarly, if $a_n\ge cb_n\ge 0$ for some constant $c$, then $\sum_na_n$ will diverge if $\sum_nb_n$ diverges.

EDIT: Just to be explicit, you have shown there exists $c,C$ such that $0\le cb_n\le a_n\le Cb_n$, so $\sum_na_n$ converges *if and only if* $\sum_nb_n$ converges.